# Apache Kafka Maven package name for client admin

Tags: maven, apache-kafka

For using AdminClient, I need to import:
org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClient package name.

I downloaded:
org.apache.kafka:kafka_2.11:0.10.0.13
org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:0.10.0.11 dependencies from maven repository in IntelliJ idea.

However, my desired import statement is not found. What is the specific package name for AdmintClient to download ? (kafka 0.11.0.2 is not exist in the IntelliJ Maven Search)

Comment: please share your `pom.xml` and the code that is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `AdminClient` classes are in the `kafka-clients` maven package.

However you need a version more recent than 0.10.0 as the AdminClient was only added in 0.11.

If you can, I recommend to use the latest version (currently 2.0.0) as the AdminClient has evolved quite a bit since it first appeared.

Maven artifact: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka-clients/2.0.0

Comment: I don't know if newer AdminClient works with the old brokers, though, if the APIs at the broker won't accept the requests